# Moving project to another directory causes missing view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-cli

I created a project with the dotnet cli and everything worked up until the time I wanted to write tests for the app.
I created a `src` directory and moved the entire web project to the `src` folder after which I created the test project in a folder called `tests`.

I added reference to the web app in the test project, the test run successfully but when I run my app with `dotnet run` I get the following error:

[image]

> The `Views` folder is in the `src` directory and every other files including the *.csproj.

Please find my folder structure below:

[image: Folder Structure]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: it cannot find any file called Index.cshtml in the mentioned locations. If you moved your code from `/Views/` to `/src/Views`, move the entire project.

Comment: The Views are present in the `src` folder.

Comment: Well, so you did move them and now it cannot find them. You need to move the entire project, not just the source code.

Comment: I need a solution instead of simply down voting the question.

Comment: I have already told you the solution: you need to move the **entire project**. Isn't the error message clear? You moved the files but not the project (*.csproj)

Comment: I moved everything in the project including *.csproj

Comment: @JohnKennedy can you please share your project with me ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe github or an online storageService (dropbox/onedrive/etc)

Comment: Here is the link to the code https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zj-UOB9SBjziYNpplClhTPF0Iz5V6910

Comment: @JohnKennedy See my updated answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

I see what your problem is now, in launch.json ,change

```
cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
```

to

```
cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\src",
```

This is related to vs code,you need to tell it which folder is the workspace
Your code was working fine on Visual Studio
Also,don't forget to remove

```
products.Add("Error", null);
```

**Original Post:**

Not sure which is your current folder structure but let's take your original example.

If you just move the "Views" folder inside a src folder you can add the following in your Startup.cs file :

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //..
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < o.ViewLocationFormats.Count; i++)
                o.ViewLocationFormats[i] = "/src" + o.ViewLocationFormats[i];
        });
    }
```

Now,if you moved other resources too(css,images) you'll have to update any references to them.
I don't see why you should deviate from the convention though,create a new clean project ,with tests and see what's different from you project

Comment: I have tried that initially before I asked the question. Did you try setting up the project in VSCode?

Comment: @JohnKennedy ,yes. That was my only change

Comment: this worked. I added this line `products.Add("Error", null);` intentionally.